# GMail API Error: Path "{userId}/messages/send" misses a "userId" parameter. Is this a bug?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, gmail, gmail-api

I am attempting to send email via the .NET API for GMail from within a Unity3D script. Unfortunately I'm having some trouble. The following code is called whenever I press the "R" key in-game.

```
//MEMBERS INCLUDED AT TOP OF CLASS
//TextAsset credFile;
//static String AppName = "Redacted-Appname";
//
//List<string> Scopes = new List<string>() { "GMAIL_SEND" };



if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        UserCredential emailerCredential;

        //Create Credential
        using (MemoryStream credStream = new MemoryStream(credFile.bytes))
        {
            string credPath = "token.json";
            emailerCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(credStream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "myDoubleCheckedEmailAddress@redacted.com",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }

        //Create Service using credential
        GmailService service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = emailerCredential,
            ApplicationName = AppName
        });

        //Create Mail Message
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
            "myDoubleCheckedEmailAddress@redacted.com",
            "DoubleCheckedTOEmailAddress@redacted.com",
            "Test Email Using GMail API",
            "This is a test of the emergency llama system.");

        //Create Gmail Message
        Message emailmsg = new Message();
        //ConvertMail Message to URL Encoded Base64 string and feed it into Gmail message
        emailmsg.Raw = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message.ToString())));
        string userId = "myDoubleCheckedEmailAddress@redacted.com";
        service.Users.Messages.Send(emailmsg, userId).Execute();
    }
```

As a result of this code, I end up with the following exception:

> ArgumentException: Path "{userId}/messages/send" misses a "userId"
>   parameter UnityLoader.js:1043 Parameter name: {userId}/messages/send
>   UnityLoader.js:1043   at
>   Google.Apis.Requests.RequestBuilder.BuildRestPath () [0x00000] in
>   <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0  UnityLoader.js:1043 --- End of
>   stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   UnityLoader.js:1043   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

I believe that the Request builder is building {userId} into the REST request instead of inserting the actual username. Looking for someone with more experience to confirm/deny this. Is this a bug, or am I doing it wrong?

Assuming that this is a bug I'm going to go post it on the GMail.Net API github here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues

Comment: Looks like there's some kind of dictionary it's reading to do the interpolation but the dictionary doesn't have a `userID` key.

Comment: *In response to deleted comment* The ``Message`` class here is from ``Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data``. I also tried changing Message to var (implicit type) and got the same result.

Comment: Try using `Scopes = new List<string>() { GmailService.Scope.GmailSend };`

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks for the tips, but unfortunately, still no dice. I got the EXACT same result. after changing ``Scopes``

Comment: If you think it is a bug, it is better if you post it directly at Google's Public Issue tracker https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker. But before this check: 1. After modifying the scope, delete your credentials in `~/.credentials/*.json` in order to start a new authorization flow. 2. Make sure that you include all necessary libraries. 3. See if you can solve the issue by strictly following the samples( https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet and https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send - with the scope `GmailService.Scope.GmailSend`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this as a bug report to the Google Github and it was recorded there as such. I was, however, informed that Unity3D was not a supported platform, and as such the issue was of low priority. If anyone wants to fix this, they'll have to branch the repo.